# Is a limit that has left hand and right hand sides of -infinity and infinity considered as Not Finite?

Tags: calculus, limits

I had this wording problem, where I got confused over whether a limit that does not exist, is considered not finite, because its not infinity nor -infinity either.

Comment: Something that **does not exist** is neither finite nor infinite. When we say that a limit is infinite, we mean that it is "larger" than every number.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh so can we state that it is "Not Finite"?

Comment: If you say "not finite" it's not clear what you mean - that phrasing could be interpreted as meaning that the limit is infinite, i.e., both sides tend to $\pm \infty$, and the function either increases or decreases without bound from both sides. If you say "the limit does not exist," your point is a lot clearer.